# How to render Asset Entry content in a JSP in Liferay 7

Tags: jsp, liferay, liferay-7, liferay-aui

I have created a "basic web content" entry in my liferay. In Asset Publisher, I can display it via the following:

```
<liferay-ui:asset-display
    assetEntry="<%= assetEntry %>"
    assetRenderer="<%= assetRenderer %>"
    assetRendererFactory="<%= assetRendererFactory %>"
    showExtraInfo="<%= assetPublisherDisplayContext.isShowExtraInfo() %>"
/>
```

But that means I have no control over the content. So, I wanted to get the content using the following:

```
JournalArticleLocalService.getArticle(assetEntry.getClassPK());
```

However, that throws an error: `No JournalArticle exists with the primary key 58637`. Thoughts? Any help?

I am assuming that `Web Content Article` means `Journal Article`, since I haven't found any web content service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning your error: An journal AssetEntry references an JournalArticle by its `resourcePrimKey` which is not the primary key of the JournalArticle you are going to use in `JournalArticleLocalService.getArticle(long)`.
A reason is that JournalArticles are versioned. You can try to do the following:
`JournalArticleLocalService.fetchLatestArticle(assetEntry.getClassPK());` to fetch the latest journal article version.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure if I'm thick, the docs aren't great, or the combination of the two.